# LibGDX Tiled Map collision detection failing

Tags: java, android, libgdx, pacman

I am implementing a pacman clone and right now i am at that case where i am trying to move the character by swiping . somehow in some cases the way is open but the canMove() returns a false :S

Here is a sample of the map : [image: Map Sample]

and here is the canMove method :

```
 public boolean canMove(String direction,ArrayList<Tile> walls){
    Rectangle testBound=new Rectangle();
    switch(direction){
        case "up":
            testBound.set(posX,posY+movement,length,width);
            break;
        case "down":
            testBound.set(posX,posY-movement,length,width);
            break;
        case "left":
            testBound.set(posX-movement,posY,length,width);
            break;
        case "right":
            testBound.set(posX+movement,posY,length,width);
            break;

    }
    for(Tile f:walls){
        if(testBound.overlaps(f.getBound())){
            System.out.println(f.getPosX()+","+f.getPosY());
            return  false;
        }
    }
    return true;

}
```

I really appreciate if someone could tell me what am i doing wrong . please note that the Rectangles around the sides and the characters are both the same width and height .

Comment: What are the values of `length`, `width`, and `movement` (I assume those values are the same every time you call `canMove`)?  What code are you using to populate `walls`?